# R summation pivot table

Tags: r

for a data frame as follow

```
id<-c(1,1,2,3,3,2)
p<-c(10,0,22,34,0,0)
df<-data.frame(id,p)
```

I need a summary table like

```
id   p
1    10
2    22
3    34
```

which is actually aggregated summation of p for each id.
can I get this with 'dcast'?

Comment: Note that you have not created a `data.frame` with `df = c("id", "p")`. Instead, you have created a vector with two strings.

Comment: @mrdwab:yes.. I just corrected it. I meant to create a data frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need `dcast`? Try `aggregate` in base R:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,3,3,2),
                 p = c(10,0,22,34,0,0))
aggregate(df, by=list(id), sum)
#   Group.1 id  p
# 1       1  2 10
# 2       2  4 22
# 3       3  6 34
```

You can also trick `dcast` as below. Your data is not quite in the expected "molten" form for `dcast`:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, id ~ ., value.var = "p", sum)
#   id NA
# 1  1 10
# 2  2 22
# 3  3 34
```

Comment: Just a little improvement for the output (colnames) : 
`aggregate(list(p=df$p), by=list(id=df$id), sum)`

Comment: @Alan, yes, that's nicer looking output.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways you to obtain the desired results, here are a few:
You could use `split` and `sapply`:

```
df <- data.frame(id, p)
sapply(split(df, df$id), function(x) sum(x$p))
 1  2  3 
10 22 34
```

Or a lot shorter with with `tapply`:

```
 tapply(p, id, sum)
 1  2  3 
10 22 34
```

Or you can use `ddply` from the `plyr` package:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(id), function(x) sum(x$p))
  id V1
1  1 10
2  2 22
3  3 34
```

Finally you could also use `by`:

```
 by(p, id, sum)
id: 1
[1] 10
------------------------------------------------------------ 
id: 2
[1] 22
------------------------------------------------------------ 
id: 3
[1] 34
```